# Where is \textunderscore defined ?

Tags: syntax

I just started TeX recently and I'm reworking a legacy TeX-piece (book , second edition).
I create lots of TeX-tables (with SAS) and do \input them.
The tables contain many  \textunderscore s.
All show up in my  pdf  as  upshifted points and not as underscores.
Adding a package{hyperref}  induces many errors that are absent without that package.

Who knows what could be the reason and what to do ?

Werner.

Comment: Can you post one of those "many errors" induced by hyperref?

Answer (score 6):

What font encoding are you using? `\textunderscore` is not available except in typerwriter fonts in the default font encoding, OT1, that is, in the font encoding you get if you don't or your installation doesn't explicitly specify another.  However, it is available via T1 font encoding.  Therefore, you might try explicitly setting your font encoding to T1 (add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` before loading `hyperref`).

If that doesn't work, you might try some other fonts to the one(s) you're using, keeping the T1 fontencoding, eg, `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}` to load palatino fonts.

If that doesn't work (which would be very strange), try adding

```
\def\textunderscore{\char\`_}
```

to your code immediately after `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Finally, if none of this works (and I'd be most surprised if it didn't), latex.ltx defines `\textunderscore` (almost) like this:

```
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textunderscore}{%
  \leavevmode \kern.06em\vbox{\hrule width .3em}}
```

Try including those lines in your document preamble (again, after `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and before loading `hyperref`). NB, the result won't look that great, but nevertheless, better than no underscore at all!